# Get protocol, hostname, and path from URL

Tags: javascript, regex

I have made a Regular expression that captures the Short URL of a link. For example:

```
https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=picture%20of%20a%20potato
```

My regular expression would be:

```
/(https:\/\/.+?)\/.+/
```

Now this would only capture:

```
https://www.google.com
```

What I want to do now is store the captured RegEx into a variable. Any help or suggestions are greatly appreciated.

Comment: When you call `.match()` it returns an array containing the match and all the capture groups. BTW, there's no point in putting a capture group around the entire regexp.

Comment: https://www.abeautifulsite.net/parsing-urls-in-javascript

Comment: [`/(https?:.*?\.{1,3})/gi` won't capture  `https://www.google.com`](https://regex101.com/r/CEntTi/2)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your regex won't capture `https://www.google.com`.

Use capturing group and apply your regex with `regex.exec()`. Then access the returned array to set your variable:

```js
str="https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=picture%20of%20a%20potato";
regex = new RegExp('(https?://.*?\)/');
match = regex.exec(str)[1];
console.log(match);
```

Answer (score 4):

The `<a>` DOM element provides this sort of splitting of hrefs for you! Here is how:

```
var a = document.createElement('a');
a.href = 'https://www.google.com/webhp?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8#q=picture%20of%20a%20potato';
console.log({
        protocol: a.protocol,
        host: a.host,
        hostname: a.hostname,
        port: a.port,
        pathname: a.pathname,
        search: a.search
});
```

returns:

```
{
  "protocol": "https:",
  "host": "www.google.com",
  "hostname": "www.google.com",
  "port": "",
  "pathname": "/webhp",
  "search": "?sourceid=chrome-instant&ion=1&espv=2&ie=UTF-8"
}
```

See https://www.abeautifulsite.net/parsing-urls-in-javascript for more information.

Answer (score 0):

You don't need the "g" flag, so it'd be

```
var matchResult = someUrlString.match(/(https?:.*?\.{1,3})/i);
```

Then `matchResult` would be an array (or `null`). If not `null`, your regex would result in indexes 0 and 1 both containing the matched text.

Your regular expression, for the record, matches things like

- http:foo.
- https:zimbabwe_is_nice...
- http:Hello my name is Adam and have you considered aluminum siding? It can save you thousands in upkeep costs.